# Digest loop in Angular

Tags: angularjs

Why does digest loop not trigger for the following code, even though the `now` variable is changed?

```
var app = angular.module('coolName',['ngResource']);

app.controller('TimeController', function($scope) {
$scope.now = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();

setInterval(function() {
  $scope.now = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
  console.log($scope.now);
}, 1000);

});
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `$interval` instead of `setInterval`:

```
app.controller('TimeController', function($scope, $interval) {
    $interval(function() {
        $scope.now = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
        console.log($scope.now);
    }, 1000);
});
```

`setInterval` is not an angular construct so it doesn't trigger the digest cycle. However, `$interval` is, and thus it triggers the cycle.

Answer (score 0):

You wont have access to `$scope` in `setInterval`, but you can get access to the scope by using:

```
var $myscope = angular.element([Some DOMElement]).scope();
```

then call the same code you have already followed by `$digest()`:

```
$myscope.now = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
$myscope.$digest(); // this will refresh the UI
```